# C# List + Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have this code in C#.
It is returning "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.

Code:

```
    public decimal Calculate(String id)
    {
        decimal Total=0;
        AmountDataDB getData=new AmountDataDB();
        List<AmountData> d = new List<AmountData>();
        d = getData.Amount_Details(id);
        if (d.Capacity != 0)
        {
            foreach (AmountData temp in d)//NullReference exception occurs here
            {
                Total += temp.Amount;
            }

        }
        return Total;
    }
```

Here, AmountDataDB and AmountData are two classes. Amount_Details returns a list of type AmountData.

Comment: Your AmountData object in your list is possibly NULL.  Check it

Comment: Are you positive that Amount_Details isn't returning null?

Comment: If it was returning null, then `if(d.capacity...)` should throw the exception

Comment: @ck, maybe that's where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @user372066 are you sure exception is thrown at foreach line?

Comment: please provide a stacktrace for this problem, we could need that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getData.Amount_Details(id);` returns `null`, probably because there are no records for that particular id. You probably should change the behaviour of `Amount_Details()` to return an empty list instead of null if there are no records.

Comment: Surely that would crash when he called capacity on the null reference on the next line, not at the foreach? (agreed with the advice though, never return null collections!)

Comment: hm, you are right. Either it has to occur in the conditional or in the foreach block (because either d or temp are null) but in the foreach-decleration? hm.

Comment: Is there any way that the result of Amount_Details could be a subclass of `List<>` that has overridden the GetEnumerator() method? I wouldn't have thought that was possible, but I can't think what else happens on the foreach line.

Comment: This could be possible. But without a call stack it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 4):

Non-answer (advice):

Please, please x 100000, dont ever write code like:

```
List<AmountData> d = new List<AmountData>();
d = getData.Amount_Details(id);
```

It is totally pointless creating a new list only to have it overwritten in the next line.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to ensure that the `d` variable is never null:

```
List<AmountData> d = getData.Amount_Details(id) ?? new List<AmountData>();
```